# Getting broken images on localhost but not on websites

Tags: c#, asp.net

On our website we have images dropped on a grid with the following line:

```
imgUpdated.ImageUrl = "./images/Test_Icon.gif";
```

This works fine when published to production or test websites but within the IDE it gives broken (Red-X) images. Properties on the broken image says this:

```
http://localhost:52168/OurApp/images/Test_Icon.gif
```

If I attempt to past that into a browser, it redirects me to the login page with the following URL:

```
http://localhost:52168/OurApp/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fITRequest%2fimages%2fTest_Icon.gif
```

I'd appreciate any help you might offer.  I've already tried setting up a virtual directory in IIS and taking out the period but that didn't help.

Comment: Did you take out both the period and the slash? `images/...`

Comment: @AustinMullins I hadn't.  But that didn't help either.

Comment: wow, people still use gifs :)

Comment: @KeithNicholas not that personally care about people still using IE6 but no transparent png's if you do.

Comment: what if you put a web.config file in the `/images/` folder with allow anonymous in it?

Comment: @Eonasdan - There is the following in the site's web.config
 <location path="~/images">
  <system.web>
   <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
   </authorization>
  </system.web>
 </location>
Are you looking for something different?

Comment: try a `?` that will allow anonymous users

Comment: Is "/OurApp/" part of the test and production application URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a `web.config` file with the following xml and place it in your images folder

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="?"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This is likely the reason your IDE doesn't show the images. If your browser is giving a `401` response and redirecting to your login page, the IDE is expecting an image MINE type.

You can find [more information](http://weblogs.asp.net/gurusarkar/archive/2008/09/29/setting-authorization-rules-for-a-particular-page-or-folder-in-web-config.aspx) on the authorization section

Comment: Eonasdan - Thanks so very much. That did the trick. BTW: What is the difference between the "*" in your answer and the "?" in the edit, because <allow users="?"/> did not work and <allow users="*"/> did.

Comment: `*` is authorized users and `?` means anonymous. I added a link to my answer

Comment: For some reason in my last comment "*" did not have the asterisk between the quotes.  Anyway the asterisk did work while the question mark did not.

Answer (score 0):

Your image or any other content paths should start with forward slash **/** which points always to the root of your website. That way no matter in what environment you are your path will always be the same. So, answering your question... your path should look like this:

```
imgUpdated.ImageUrl = "/images/Test_Icon.gif";
```

Comment: That brings me to "http://localhost:52168/images/Test_Icon.gif" which is still a broken link and (in a new browser window) goes to a "HTTP Error 404 - Not Found." error.

Comment: the point of the `./` or `../` or `~/` is so you don't have to hard code the absolute path to the url.